# DQS - Appy ends with rule

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ssis, data-quality-services

I am working one project which is performing **data cleansing** task ,for which I am using **DQS (SQL Server instance)** for data cleansing and transformation.

I have once excel file as Input.

```
Address
-------
1201 Elm St Ste 4400
140 N Wright St
ABC Corp.
Tender house
```

Now I want to apply below rule in DQS in **address** column.

```
if value ends with "corp." then replace it with "corporation"
if value ends with "st" then replace it with "street".
```

So output should be as below:

```
Address_output
---------
1201 Elm St Ste 4400
140 N Wright street
ABC corporation
Tender house
```

**Note:** I can do replace by using Term based relations, but how to do if "Ends with" condition.
Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do with end with street, better to go with script component and regular expression.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, We can use it as an alternative. However, I need to apply DQS in All Rules in our project. This single rule is not being achieved by DQS,so I have posted this question.